# Is there any way to speedup the list selection further?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider some test data:

```
DataSamples = 
  Join[Partition[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7], 1], 
   Partition[Sqrt[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7]], 1], 2];
DataSamples2 = Exp[-DataSamples];
```

I would like to perform a test selection:

```
index1 = 1;
index2 = 2;
SelData[data_, index1_, index2_, value1_, value2_] := 
 Select[data, #[[index1]] > value1 && #[[index2]] < value2 &]
```

This realization is very slow:

```
SelData[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {17.1745,Null}

Alternatively, I may make a compiled selection:

```
SelDataCompiled = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 
      2}, {index1, _Integer}, {index2, _Integer}, {value1, _Real}, \
{value2, _Real}}, 
    Select[data, #[[index1]] > value1 && #[[index2]] < value2 &], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // 
  ReleaseHold
SelDataCompiled[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 
   0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.671522,Null}

Is there any way to speedup this selection and similar ones further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite fast.  Does it compile too?  (I haven't installed a compiler.)

```
PickData[data_, index1_, index2_, value1_, value2_] :=
 Pick[data,
  UnitStep[-data[[All, index1]] + value1] +
   UnitStep[data[[All, index2]] - value2], 0]

PickData[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.747338, Null}

Compared with

```
SelData[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {19.7634, Null}

***For compiling***

`Pick` may not compile, i.e.

```
Map[MemberQ[Map[ToString, Compile`CompilerFunctions[]], #] &,
 {"Pick", "UnitStep"}]
```

> {False, True}

so perhaps use this version

```
PartData[data_, index1_, index2_, value1_, value2_] :=
 Part[data, Flatten@Position[
    UnitStep[-data[[All, index1]] + value1] +
     UnitStep[data[[All, index2]] - value2], 0]]
```

All the above functions are compilable

```
Map[MemberQ[Map[ToString, Compile`CompilerFunctions[]], #] &,
 {"Part", "Flatten", "Position", "UnitStep"}]
```

> {True, True, True, True}

```
PartDataCompiled = Hold@Compile[{
     {data, _Real, 2}, {index1, _Integer},
     {index2, _Integer}, {value1, _Real}, {value2, _Real}},
    Part[data, Flatten@Position[
       UnitStep[-data[[All, index1]] + value1] +
        UnitStep[data[[All, index2]] - value2], 0]],
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // ReleaseHold
PartDataCompiled[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: On my machine `PickData` is 0.64s and `PartDataCompiled` is 0.75s

Comment: @IntroductionToProbability Thanks for the info.

Comment: I love the way you used `CompilerFunctions[]` to check if a function could be compiled. I have not thought to do this algorithmically and been referencing stackexchange pages to check manually  "-_-