# Why association slows down compiled function in the following example?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile, associations

Consider the following code, which generates some data and performs some selections:

```
DataSamples = 
  Join[Partition[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7], 1], 
   Partition[Sqrt[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7]], 1], 2];
DataSamples2 = Exp[-DataSamples];
SelDataCompiled = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data, _Real, 
      2}, {index1, _Integer}, {index2, _Integer}, {value1, _Real}, \
{value2, _Real}}, 
    Select[data, #[[index1]] > value1 && #[[index2]] < value2 &], 
    CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // 
  ReleaseHold
index1=1;
index2=2;
SelDataCompiled[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.3, 
   0.7]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

I would like to make an association corresponding to different sets of the values `value1, value2`:

```
SelDataAssociation[data_, index1_, index2_, set_] := 
 Association[{{data, index1, index2, "1"} -> 
     SelDataCompiled[data, index1, index2, 0.5, 0.5], {data, index1, 
      index2, "2"} -> 
     SelDataCompiled[data, index1, index2, 0.3, 0.7], {data, index1, 
      index2, "3"} -> 
     SelDataCompiled[data, index1, index2, 0.1, 0.9]}][{data, index1, 
   index2, set}]
```

This code works a bit slower than if just calling the compiled function:

```
SelDataAssociation[DataSamples2, index1, index2, "1"]; // AbsoluteTiming
SelDataCompiled[DataSamples2, index1, index2, 0.5, 
       0.5]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.24648,Null}

> {0.652332,Null}

Could you please tell me how to use associations efficiently in the given case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelDataAssociation` is 3x slower because it calls `SelDataCompiled` 3 times.

Are you looking for a convenient way to call your values? If so set up an association like `mappings`

```
keys = CharacterRange["1", "3"];
values = {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.9}};
mappings =  AssociationThread[keys, values] 
(* <|"1"->{0.5`,0.5`},"2"->{0.3`,0.7`},"3"->{0.1`,0.9`}|> *) 

foo[data_, index1_, index2_, key_] :=  SelDataCompiled[data, index1, index2, mappings[key][[1]], mappings[key][[2]]]

foo[DataSamples2, index1, index2, "1"]; // AbsoluteTiming (* 0.655975 *)

foo[DataSamples2, index1, index2, "1"] === 
 SelDataAssociation[DataSamples2, index1, index2, "1"] (* True *)
```

---

*After thought*

Personally I would prefer to redefine the selector function to take a list as an argument,
eg:

`f[data_, index1_, index2_, {value1_, value2_}]`

instead of

`f[data_, index1_, index2_, value1_, value2_]`

and then use `Part` directly on `values` instead of creating an association.

ie:

```
values = {{0.5, 0.5}, {0.3, 0.7}, {0.1, 0.9}};

(* using Chris Degnen answer from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/276400/60568 instead of SelDataCompiled *)
PickData2[data_, index1_, index2_, {value1_, value2_}] := 
 Pick[data, 
  UnitStep[-data[[All, index1]] + value1] + 
   UnitStep[data[[All, index2]] - value2], 0];

PickData2[DataSamples2, index1, index2, values[[1]]] === 
 SelDataAssociation[DataSamples2, index1, index2, "1"] (* True *)
```

This has the benefit of being able to use `Map` across `values` which is faster as it autocompiles.

```
PickData2[DataSamples2, index1, index2, #] & /@ values; // RepeatedTiming
(* 1.77766 *)
```

vs

```
SelDataAssociation[DataSamples2, index1, index2,"1"]; // RepeatedTiming
(* 2.30011 *)
```